# How can I change titles in action section in Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I want to change titles in action section in Django admin. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: You can define a translation file: https://github.com/django/django/blob/e1a093f8cba66574ce516a7510ded5196cdc6416/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [description <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e1a093f8cba66574ce516a7510ded5196cdc6416/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L17) is defined in the `django.contrib.admin.actions` module with:

> ```
> @action(
>     permissions=["delete"],
>     description=gettext_lazy("Delete selected %(verbose_name_plural)s"),
> )
> def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
>     # …
> ```

It takes the `verbose_name_plural` of the model. You thus can change the `verbose_name_plural` with:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'publications'
        # …
```

or you can make a translation file that translates it to something else, but you are limited to what the Django modeladmin passes to the formatter.